# php bin/magento setup:upgrade gives error (localhost ubuntu 16.04)

Tags: dom, magento2

PHP bin/Magento module:status

I am making magneto simple custom module but give me below error.

```
    user@user:/opt/lampp/htdocs/magento2$ php bin/magento module:status 
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'DOMDocument' not found in /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Config/Dom.php:364
Stack trace:
#0 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Config/Dom.php(109): Magento\Framework\Config\Dom->_initDom('<?xml version="...')
#1 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Config/Reader/Dom.php(70): Magento\Framework\Config\Dom->__construct('<?xml version="...', Object(Magento\Framework\App\Arguments\ValidationState), Array, 'xsi:type', NULL)
#2 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Config/Reader/Filesystem.php(146): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Config\Reader\Dom->_createConfigMerger('Magento\\Framewo...', '<?xml version="...')
#3 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Config/Reader/Filesystem.php(127): Magento\Framework\Config\Reader\Filesystem->_readFiles(Object(Magento\Framework\Config\FileIterator))
#4 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/App/ObjectManagerFactory.php(269): Magento\Framework\Config in /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Config/Dom.php on line 364
```

i even installed dom by using below command 
restarted the apache2 again but same error /
usser@user:/opt/lampp/htdocs/magento2$ sudo apt-get install php5.6-dom

Answer (score 0):

Hey will you please try setup:upgrade command after removing generated files using following command..

rm -rf var/di var/generation var/cache var/page_cache var/view_preprocessed

The problem might not of the Dom may be.

Comment: I tried this also but nothing happens .Same error of class DOMDocument not found in same class as above .

Comment: one more thing i am executing all commands in Magento root folder as stated in magent2 documentation.